# Inject into static field Kotlin/Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, static, kotlin

Im trying to inject a value into a static field in Kotlin, but I`m not having success.

I know a workaround with Java, so in Kotlin, what`s the equivalent for this Java code?

```
@Component
public class GlobalValue {

    public static String DATABASE;

    @Value("${mongodb.db}")
    public void setDatabase(String db) {
        DATABASE = db;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thought this was gonna work:

```java
@Component
class GlobalValue {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        lateinit var database: String
        @Value("\${myprop.testing2}") set
    }
}
```

But it doesn't, for some reason, possibly, because generated setter is `final`, or because it goes through `Companion` object, I don't know.

This works tho:

```java
@Component
class GlobalValue {
    companion object {
        @JvmField
        var database: String = "test"
    }

    @Value("\${myprop.testing2}")
    fun setDatabase(db: String) {
        database = db
    }
}
```

Note the `\` in `@Value` - it's because otherwise we would have a conflict with the language itself, such construct [is already there.](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8061)
Also, you need to specify a default value, `lateinit` is impossible with `@JvmField`.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, the following should be equivalent:

```
@Component
class GlobalValue {
    companion object {
        @JvmField
        lateinit var DATABASE: String
    }

    @Value("\${mongodb.db}")
    fun setDatabase(db: String) {
        DATABASE = db;
    }
}
```

Comment: As Shadov is saying in their answer, lateinit is not possible with the @JvmField annotation.

Comment: In that case, I recommend writing this file in Java.