# Difficulty in @Value Injection in @PropertySource in Kotlin/SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, kotlin-lateinit

I am new to Kotlin. So I was trying to write a `@PropertySource` class with `@Value` injection in Spring Boot, so that it can be used elsewhere.

I have written the class like this:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource


@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:app-properties.properties")
class AppProperties {

    companion object {

        @Value("\${app.storage.types}")
        lateinit var appStorageType : String

        @Value("\${app.device.supported-protocols}")
        lateinit var appDeviceSupportedProtocols : String
        
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
    }
}
```

But when I run the application, I get the error in my:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": [
            "lateinit property appStorageType has not been initialized"
        ]
    }
}
```

I am trying to fetch the properties in other classes like:

```
AppProperties.appStorageType
```

When I was in Java we had getters and setters to do it. What is the equivalent in Kotlin?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inject into static field Kotlin/Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50567482/inject-into-static-field-kotlin-spring-boot)

Comment: Thanks.. I will give it a try and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Just initialize this properties in app-properties.properties file..

Create app-properties.properties file and put this line

```
app.storage.types.appStorageType=some value
app.device.supported-protocols.appDeviceSupportedProtocols=other value
```

Comment: Unfortunately I tried that. I added the variable name to the property name's end, but still get that error. :(